# React: Accessing form element data from another component

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple form element in React:

```
class QueryForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'Enter Query'
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A Query was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <form>
        <label>
          <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I use this element in another Element like so:

```
const FormViz = ({ queryString }) => {
  queryString = `SELECT * FROM TABLE02`;
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CONST_QUERY, {
    variables: { queryString },
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return;
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
        <QueryForm />
        <button>Run</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `Run` button will basically spit out the text in the form (which is basically a text box). But how do I access it?

Answer (score 1):

it's not spit out :)
Buttons by default submit forms.
JavaScript provides a method to handle such cases, so you could write your button as such:

```
<button onClick{(e) => { 
  e.preventDefault() 
  // Other button logic
}>Run<button>
```

You could read more on it at the [MDN Official Documantation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)